# problems installing bs4 on python3 with conda on windows 10

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, windows-10, conda

If anyone has had this problem before and come across a solution then please share. If I try

```
import bs4
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I get this error if i try to import any variation of beautifulsoup4 (capitalized, with no number etc). But if I check that the module is installed:

```
conda list beautifulsoup4
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda list beautifulsoup4
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3:
#
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0                     <pip>
```

I've tried removing the packages and reinstalling with conda or pip and the same result always happens. If I check where its installed the appropriate package seems to be installed and unpacked in the right place:

```
C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py34_0\Lib\site-packages\bs4
```

I've tried running the test programs in the directory and it returns the error described above. 'no bs4', I tried typing help('modules') into the shell but there is no sign of a beautifulsoup module at all which is unexpected given that conda list says its installed.

I've had no problems installing other packages with conda and can't see any obvious solution to this. Any help would be great?

Comment: did you try in spyder which comes with anaconda install?

Comment: Add env variable path C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py34_0\Lib\site-packages\

Comment: tried adding to the path, it doesn't change anything. But for some reason Spyder will import the module! I've no idea why though? But thanks!